# Hit an URL once a day

Tags: .net

I want to make sure a link is hit once (and only once) a day in my website built in .net, 
I'm on a shared server so cant run an executable - and have no access to a pc that is switched on 24hrs to create a scheduled task.

What are my options?

Comment: Can you clarify,  is it once per day regarding of an application restart?  Does the result need to be saved?  If the application restarts does the result need to be read back in from disk?

Comment: @MAfifi - essentnally i need to execute a block of code that does a few things inculding saving to the db.by hiting a url i can execute that block of code

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cache class - when adding a new cache entry you can set it to expire in 24 hours and pass in the event handler to execute when it does expire.

In the event handler you can reset the cache entry.

See [`Cache.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add.aspx) and the parameter for `onRemoveCallback`:

> onRemoveCallback - 
>   Type: `System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback`
>   A delegate that, if provided, is called when an object is removed from the cache. You can use this to notify applications when their objects are deleted from the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Would a cron job be a possibility?

```
0 0 * * * curl -q http://www.example.com/page.aspx
```

Comment: »and have no access to a pc that is switched on 24hrs to create a scheduled task« – you may instead suggest a WebCron service.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option then would be a static constructor + Timer + some safe guard about ensuring it will only run once per day.

You may want to improve this to ensure a few things like, don't wait for a full day for the first run.  Don't wait for a full day if the previous run was 23 hours ago.  Some maths essentially to ensure that the next run is 24 hours from when it has ran.

Something like,

```
private static DateTime _lastNavigated;
private static Timer _myTimer

static MyObject()
{
    _myTimer = new Timer(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    _myTimer.Elapsed += MyOnceADayCode;
    _myTimer.Enabled = true;
}

public static void MyOnceADayCode(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    _lastNavigated = DateTime.UtcNow;
    if (DateTime.UtcNow > _lastNavigated.AddDays(1))
    {
        // Haven't navigated in the last day, need to navigate again
    }
}
```

Another idea (depending on whether your account will have access), is to create (using code) a scheduled task.  There some good wrapper classes out there that use COM to do all the work for you.  You'll still need a static constructor to ensure the code is executed on app load.

Answer (score 0):

To perform scheduled tasks from within your website using ASP.NET, I suggest you to read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc).